# how to create hierarchical blockchin using Geth, ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, private-blockchain

As of my plan (in the attached figure) there will be 2 levels of blockchain. The top level blockchain (yellow circles) consist of 4 participant, admin top & admins middle. The bottom levels blockchain (green circle) consists of a middle admin and some child in it. So middle admins have to participate in two blockchains.  [image]
My question,
**1) how to setup two blockchain in a single node (admin middle)

2) How to deploy smart contracts here ?

3) how to get the  measures block creation time, response time and energy consumption?**
I'm using Geth, Ethereum, solidity on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a concept called hierarchical blockchains.

If your concept requires some interaction between the blockchains you have to use something else than Geth, but I have no idea where you could start. The whole concept is rather... weird. Which doesn't necessarily mean anything bad, just unheard of.

Comment: can a node participate in two blockchain ?

Comment: Not any node I know of. A node is designed to be a single one within a single blockchain.